# Sort an array of objects in Javascript by key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

First time poster, long time reader.  I’m having a problem sorting an array of objects, this is homework so I’m not asking for someone to write the code for me just point me in the right direction or show me my over sight. The object is to write a function to sort an array of objects when passing in an array and a key ie:

```
([{a:2},{b:2},{a:1},{a:3},{b:3},{b:1}], “a”)
```

Should return

```
[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{b:1},{b:2},{b:3}];
```

I can’t use anything like underscore.js or node.js

```
    //example array to use
    var testarr = [{a:2},{b:2},{a:1},{a:3},{b:3},{b:1}];
    console.log("array sort test: should look like [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{b:1},{b:2},{b:3}]");

    //first attempt 
    var sortArrayByKey = function (arr1, key) {
            (arr1.sort(function(a,b){
            return a[key] - b[key];}));
            return arr1;
    };
    //still only returns testarr
    console.log(sortArrayByKey(testarr, "a") );

    //second attempt
    var sortArrayByKey1 = function (array, key) {
    var compareByKey = function (a, b) {
            var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
            return x - y;
    }
    array.sort(compareByKey);        
    return array;
    };
    //still only returns testarr
    console.log(sortArrayByKey1(testarr, “a”));
```

![pic of requirements in-case i'm describing it wrong [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2iCF.png)

Comment: sorry but what does the key have to do with sorting it?  Are the keys just so supposed to be alphabetical, or is the key you pass supposed to be first? The problem as described is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, a key of "a" will make a's be first or a key of "b" would make b's be first. like key "a" used, then [{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{b:1},{b:2},{b:3}] is the return. If "b" is the key [{b:1},{b:2},{b:3},{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}] would be returned.

Comment: Your objects have different keys. Since you're only passing `"a"`, only those objects with an `a:` key will get a meaningful sort order.

Comment: ...by any chance are you confusing the `a` and `b` callback parameters with the `a:` and `b:` keys?

Comment: I've used the above code and it does nothing for the array. It outputs it as if it wasn't even ran threw a function in Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari. I was thinking about converting it to a string then sorting it by letter into an array then back into objects in an array once sorted but there has to be another way, i just felt like i was reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You realize checking for key `a` in the object `{b:1}` results in `undefined` don't you?

Comment: I do, the only meaningful output is when I call it by index. That's why i thought i was over looking something or is this like a trick question from the teacher to gauge our understanding of arrays vs objects?

Comment: If you pass `"a"` as the key, do you expect it to put all the `"b"` objects in order, too? How is it supposed to know what their key is so it can look up the value?

Comment: Barmar's question MUST be answered before a complete answer can be provided.  I've made a guess in my answer, but you (the designer of the problem) have to say how you want it done.  If there will only ever be one property on the object and that's the one you want used for the sort (like in your sample data), then my answer will work.  If the real world data is more complex, then you must explain how the other keys are supposed to be sorted.

Comment: @jfriend00 My solution takes the other keys into account.

Comment: I don't know, I have added a screen shot of the question with all the info I have, I hope it explains it more.

Comment: @sissonb - my solution takes the other keys into account too, but it guesses what the OP wants the algorithm to be because they haven't specified it.  That's my point.  And, what about empty objects.  And what about objects that don't have the sort key, but have multiple other keys rather than just a single key.  There are lots of cases that the OP has not specified.  I've provided two possible implementations in my answer.

Comment: Yes stated about in the first post I said this is homework and I am not looking for code just help.

Comment: The question you link to here http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2iCF.png has a mistake in it.  It says that `[{a:2},{b:2},{a:1},{a:3},{b:3},{b:1}]` should generate output of: `[{a:1},{a:2},{b:3},{b:1},{b:2},{b:3}]`, but that output doesn't even have the same objects in it.  That output is missing an `{a:3}` and has an extra `{b:3}`.

Comment: Also, the question looks like maybe the `b` items should also be sorted, but is not clear about that.  If this is homework, you should point out to the instructor that there is a mistake in the question and what should happen with the items that do not have the sort key is not specified and the question does not say whether the code must be prepared to deal with objects with more than one property.  All in all, this is horrible question.  Three things wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. I made it so you can also add more keys and sort them too.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Q9C/3/

```
function specialSort(arrayToSort, keyOrder) {
    arrayToSort = arrayToSort.sort(function (a, b) {
        for (var key in keyOrder) {
            if (!keyOrder.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                continue;
            }
            var aKey = keyOrder[key];
            if (typeof a[aKey] === "undefined" && typeof b[aKey] === "undefined") {
                continue;
            }
            if (typeof a[aKey] !== "undefined" && typeof b[aKey] === "undefined") {
                return -1;
            }
            if (typeof a[aKey] === "undefined" && typeof b[aKey] !== "undefined") {
                return 1;
            }
            if (a[aKey] > b[aKey]) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (a[aKey] < b[aKey]) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
    return arrayToSort;
}
var arrayToSort = [
    {a:2},
    {b:2},
    {a:1},
    {a:3},
    {b:3},
    {c:3},
    {c:2},
    {b:1}
];
var keyOrder = ["a", "b", "c"];
var sortedArray = specialSort(arrayToSort, keyOrder);
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortedArray));
```

Comment: TypeError: keyOrder.reverse is not a function
 

keyOrder = keyOrder.reverse();

Comment: @stephenbarker are you passing in an array as the second parameter to the function? keyOrder should be an array

Comment: That was my mistake, tonight is full of learning (remembering). Thanks that makes since now that I look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. this is a weird one. First you need to check if one of the keys is the priority key and sort based on that. Then if both keys are equal sort by the values. The problem is that there is no straightforward way to get the key but you can use the `for .. in` loop.

I'm going to assume that each object contains only one property otherwise the code will not make sense since property is unordered in objects:

```
function sortPreferredKey(arr,key) {
    arr.sort(function(a,b){
        // get the keys of each object
        for (var a_key in a) {break}
        for (var b_key in b) {break}
        if (a_key != b_key) {
            if (a_key == key) return 1;
            else if (b_key == key) return -1;
            else return 0;
        }
        return a[a_key] - b[b_key];
    });
}
```

I may have gotten the order of sort wrong but you get the idea. It's really weird that you'd even need to do something like this.

Comment: +1 I like your idiom to get the keys of each object -- I was stuck on that, so I punted in my answer.

Comment: This assumes objects will only ever have one key.  And, this provides no sort among objects that don't have the desired key.  Unclear what the OP wants to do in that case.

Comment: @jfriend00: That's deliberate - hence the `return 0` since which key is first is defined by the user (sometimes b comes before a sometimes k comes before c or z). The user only specifies one key. To specify an order the argument would have to be an array. Since javascript's sort is stable, returning 0 ensures that the objects will retain previous order if none of the keys match the arguments. Therefore the user can call this funtion multiple times to first sort by b then by z then by m etc.

Comment: @slebetman - but what happens if the input data is `[{a:1, b:-1}, {b:0, a:3}]`?  You're assuming the objects never have more than one property.  That seems dangerous in the real world, particularly since the way you get the property on the object has no guarantee of order.

Comment: @jfriend00 His question doesn't really make sense if any of the elements can have more than one property, since he wants all the b's sorted among themselves behind the a's.

Comment: @Barmar - actually per the link the OP added to the end of their question, they don't want those other elements sorted at all so the elements could have multiple properties.  It would be safer to look for the desired key first and only use the first key if the desired key is not there (as some other answers do).

Comment: @jfriend00: If he doesn't want those elements sorted then the example should return `[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{b:2},{b:3},{b:1}]` not `[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{b:1},{b:2},{b:3}]`. My interpretation is based on the example which means that the problem statement requires that objects only have one property. Of course, with the addition of the original question from the lecturer my current interpretation is that the second part of the question is wrong/buggy. The first part of the question is simple enough.

Comment: @slebetman - this link is in his question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2iCF.png which he says is the arbitrator of confusion requirements.  No doubt the question is confusing.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes I was talking about the link as well. The png requires that 'b' is sorted even though the provided key is 'a'. This only makes sense if the objects cannot contain more than one property otherwise you'd be sorting on what `in` randomly returns.

Comment: @slebetman - that link show the `b` items are NOT sorted.  Anyway, I wasted a lot of time on my answer because the OP's question was not clear.  No point in continuing our discussion.

Comment: @jfriend00: look at the png again. The input b items is in the order 2,3,1 and the result is required to be sorded: 1,2,3. Your eyes were misleading you

Comment: I see b items as 3,1,2,3 at the very end of the png.

Comment: Yeah, the question is buggy. The result requires that we remove `{a:3}` from the input and insert a duplicate `{b:3}` into the result

Comment: Right you are.  That is bogus.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can come up with. It will sort all the elements with the given key to the front; the elements without the key will be in the back, but they'll be in an unpredictable order.

```
function sortArrayByKey(arr, key) {
    function compareKey(a, b) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                return a[key] - b[key];
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    arr.sort(compareKey);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'll take it, it's the closest thing that works with out errors in firebug. So I was like 20% there, right idea, wrong tools hasOwnProperty now is added to my knowledge thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that makes a guess what to do if neither object being compared in the array has the passed in comparison key:

```
var data = [{a:2},{b:2},{a:1},{a:3},{b:3},{b:1}];

function sortByProperty(array, propName) {

    function findFirstProperty(obj) {
        for (x in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                return x;
            }
        }
    }

    return array.sort(function(first, second) {
        var firstHasProp = propName in first;
        var secondHasProp = propName in second;
        if (firstHasProp) {
            if (secondHasProp) {
                // both have the property
                return first[propName] - second[propName];
            } else {
                // only first has the property
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (secondHasProp){
            // only second has the property
            return 1;
        } else {
            // Neither sort candidate has the passed in property name
            // It is not clear what you want to do here as no other property
            //    name has been specified
            return first[findFirstProperty(first)] - second[findFirstProperty(second)]
        }
    });
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PFurT/

Logically, here's what it does:

1. If both comparison candidates have the desired property, then simply sort by the value of that property.
2. If only one comparison candidate has the desired property, then make the one with the desired property be first in the sort order
3. If neither comparison candidate has the desired property, find the first other property on the object and sort by that.  This is a guess because you don't really explain what you want to happen in this case, but it works for the data example you provided.

---

Here's a version that works like the above one, but is has been extended to sort properties that are not the passed in property in alpha order and to deal with empty objects (with no properties) so they go at the end of the sort:

```
var data = [{c:4},{a:2},{b:2},{a:1},{a:3},{b:3},{b:1},{},{c:3}];

function sortByProperty(array, propName) {
    function findFirstProperty(obj) {
        for (x in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                return x;
            }
        }
    }
    return array.sort(function(first, second) {
        var firstHasProp = propName in first;
        var secondHasProp = propName in second;
        if (firstHasProp) {
            if (secondHasProp) {
                // both have the property
                return first[propName] - second[propName];
            } else {
                // only first has the property
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (secondHasProp){
            // only second has the property
            return 1;
        } else {
            // Neither sort candidate has the passed in property name
            // It is not clear what you want to do here as no other property
            //    name has been specified
            var firstProp = findFirstProperty(first);
            var secondProp = findFirstProperty(second);
            if (firstProp === undefined && secondProp === undefined) {
                return 0;
            } else if (firstProp === undefined) {
                return 1;
            } else if (secondProp === undefined) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (firstProp === secondProp) {
                return first[firstProp] - second[secondProp];
            } else {
                return firstProp.localeCompare(secondProp);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6QsVv/

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the *sort* method is [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). The compare function:

> should be a function that accepts two arguments x and y and returns a
>   negative value if x < y, zero if x = y, or a positive value if x > y.

The function is passed the **values** in the array, so it's like calling the function with:

```
compareFunction({a:2},{b:2});
```

What you seem to want to do is sort on the property name first, then on the value. The problem with that is that you can't guarantee what order the property names are returned in. In this case, if you have **exactly** one own property for each object, you can do:

```
// Return first own property returned by in
// ORDER IS NOT GUARANTEED
function getPropName(o) {
  for (var p in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      return p;
    }
  }
}

function specialSort(array, key) {
  array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aProp = getPropName(a);
    var bProp = getPropName(b);
    // If properties are the same, compare value
    if (aProp == bProp) {
      return a[aProp] - b[bProp];
    }

    // Otherwise, compare keys
    return aProp == key? -1 : bProp == key? 1 : aProp.charCodeAt(0) - bProp.charCodeAt(0);
  });
  return array;
}
```

The above will also sort any other keys (c, d, e, etc.) after the preferred key so:

```
var a = [{c:3},{a:2},{b:2},{c:2},{a:1},{a:3},{b:3},{b:1},{c:1}]

specialSort(a, 'b'); // [{b:1}, {b:2}, {b:3}, {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}]
```